# select date using mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using the following code to get a *date* from my database:

```
$con= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","123","core");

$sql=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM transaction where date BETWEEN '7/1/204' AND '7/31/2014' ") or die ("error"); 

    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){

    $DBDate=$row['date'];

    $D=strtotime($DBDate);
    echo date('m/j/Y',$D). "<br>"; 
    }
```

My database is as follows:

```
    balance     date

    500       7/1/2014
    1000      7/7/2014
    800       7/10/2014
    1500      8/2/2014
```

When I'm selecting a range between 7/1/2014 to 7/31/2014, the 7/7/2014 is not included in the results. Both 7/1/2014 and 7/10/2014 are shown.

Please help me to get the date range as above with 7/7/2014 and tell me what is happening with 7/7/2014.

Comment: Sounds like you are using a text column to store those “dates” – if so, fix that right now, and use on of the date/time types MySQL provides.

Comment: Your date column seems of `VARCHAR` type. You better use `DATE` with the correct date format of MySQL

Comment: You should be using `DATE` or `DATETIME` columns for your dates, not `VARCHAR()`. Then you can use `BETWEEN 2014-07-01 AND 2014-07-07` for eample

Comment: I agree. It's like storing numbers as "one", "two", "three" and trying to add them up. It can probably be done but it's unnecessarily difficult.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `VARCHAR` columns then `BETWEEN` makes use of alphabetic order—that's not particularly useful when handling dates.

You first need to parse your string column and try to obtain a valid date from each row. For that, you can use the [STR_TO_DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function with appropriate format codes. Of course, unparseable dates will yield `NULL` even if they *look* correct.

(If it's not too late, just fix your DB design.)